# Query after splitting access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have splitted my ms access mdb file into front end and backend

Now i have the backend in the shared folder and frontends in users PC

i havent specified the network path anywhere in the front end to push data to the backend file

Could anyone tell me where i have to specify network path ???

Answer (score 1):

Jaison,

Look at this answer to this question that tells how to split the database...including how to re-link the tables.

[Creating the Front End MDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147702/rookie-ms-access-creating-the-front-end-mde/1147858#1147858)

Seth

Answer (score 1):

Open the front end file.  Right click on any table in the database viewer.  Pick "Linked Table Manager."  Highlight the tables you want to relink.  Make sure to check the "always ask" checkbox at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

The network path is in the linked table properties.
You have defined it when linking the table.
From the front-end, open the linked table in design view and get the properties window.
The path is displayed in the description, like
DATABASE=I:\ifs\xxx_be.mdb;TABLE=Valuation